# If/Then/Replace formula

Tags: excel, replace, formula

I know VBA is probably the way to go but I believe this can be done using a few basic formulas.

[image: My data]

I need "E2" to be replaced (cut/copy) with the contents from "A3" but only if "D2" = "Status:Active"...and so on down the sheet

the yellow and blue color-coding are only for this example and do not represent the whole sheet

this is a 7,000 line spreadsheet that was a report generated off some old system and I'm trying by best to collate and format.

Comment: Will there be data in Column `E` that will be replaced, or is it empty just waiting to be filled when `D` is "Active"

Comment: Most of them are blank but some contain additional "address" info.  ex: "Unit #2"  but maybe we can leave those alone and I can handle manually since it's only approx. 5% of the cells

Comment: Perhaps, then, consider doing a formula in `F` that uses the value from `E` when `D` is not "Active". When `D` is "Active" then it pulls from `A`. Would that make sense?

Comment: yes that's what I was trying...I think I just posted cause I'm getting frustrated but I should be able to figure that out.  thank you

Comment: Is there a reason for offsetting by one row?  It seems like an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Column `F` starting with cell `F2`

`=if(AND(E2="",D2="Status: Active"), A2, E2)`

This will test to see if `D2` has "Status: Active" and if it does, it will pull the value form `A2`. If it isn't then it will use the address already in `E2`

As explained in your comments that you are looking for A to be blank when F accepts a value from it (Cut/Paste)... there is no way for a formula to affect another cell, but... You could add a new Column `B` inserted after `A` and put the following formula in there: `=if(A2<>G2, "", A2)`. Then hide Column `A`. The new `B` column will then only show values of Column `A` when it's not already in Column `G` (formerly column `F` before the insertion of the new column).

You could also do all of this through VBA, but that seems like more effort than it's worth when some simple formulas will get you there.

Comment: that works but I'd like to CUT/PASTE the contents from A2 into E2...not Copy/paste

Comment: actually we need to add an "ISBLANK" clarification because we don't ALWAYS want the contents of A2 into E2...only when E2 ISBLANK and if D2="Status:Active"...this is where I'm getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want the column A to be blank you can try this macro out:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SwapCols()
    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim lRowNum As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lRowNum = oWs.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 2 To lRowNum

        If oWs.Range("D" & CStr(i)).Value = "Status:ACTIVE" Then

            oWs.Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value = oWs.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value
            oWs.Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value = Null

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Make sure you replace `"Sheet1"` with the name of your sheet. the macro basically checks if a cell in column D has the value `"Status:ACTIVE"` and if it does it copies the corresponding cell in column A to column E.

Just make sure if you do run this and you do not like the results do not save.